# Laravel Form Post To Wrong Route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, forms, http-post

With my App I have an orders view with search form like below

```
@include('inc.header')

@yield('content')

<form class="needs-validation" method="post" action="{{url('/wapp/orders/search')}}">
    @csrf
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Search By Order ID" name="oid">
        </div>
</form><br>
```

OrderController search function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $order = DB::table('orders')
                        ->join('users as a','a.uid', '=','orders.sender_uid')
                        ->join('users as b','b.uid', '=','orders.receiver_uid')
                        ->select('orders.oid','orders.price','orders.status','a.name as sender','b.name as receiver')
                        ->where('oid','=' , $request->oid)
                        ->first();

        if($order){
            return view('pages.search')->with('order',$order);
        }else{
            return back()->with('error','Order Not Found');

        }

    }
```

Which is successfully find the order by ID and display its results with table on the search view.

I also included the same search form in the search view in case the user wants to search for more orders,

```
@include('inc.header')

@yield('content')


<form class="needs-validation" method="post" action="{{url('/wapp/orders/search')}}">
    @csrf
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Search By Order ID" name="oid">
        </div>
</form><br>


@if ($order)


        <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">OID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Province</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                            <tr>
                            <td class="bg-success">{{$order->price}}</td>
                            <td>{{$order->oid}}</td>
                                <td>{{$order->sender}}</td>
                                <td>{{$order->receiver}}</td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{url('wapp/orders/'.$order->oid)}}" role="button">Link</a></td>
                            </tr>


                </tbody>
              </table><br>

@endif






@include('inc.footer')
```

and this is my routes :

```
Route::group(
    [           
        'namespace' => 'V1',
        'prefix' => 'wapp',
    ], function(){

        Route::get('/', 'LoginController@index');
        Route::post('/', 'LoginController@login');
        Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index');
        Route::post('/orders/search', 'OrderController@search');
        Route::get('/orders/{oid}', 'OrderController@show');

        Route::patch('/orders/{oid}', 'OrderController@update');
        Route::get('/region','RegionController@index');


});
```

My Issue is when the user enters a wrong order id or just press the search button the app will redirect to the OrderController@show which is the order details button route in the table ??!! why is that happening

Note :  If the user provide valid order ID every thing works fine !

Any ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying your browser URL and then press enter it will redirect you to the order detail page because it's a get request and on GET request, you are returning order details and you search method is defined on the POST method which should only work when POST request is made which you can only make by submitting your form.

Also, if you're doing it right then running the following command will help.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: @Rafy I'm not using browser URL, its happen when user click on the search button and as you can see its a POST request and only when user enter invalid order ID or when the search input is empty!